# Unknown yellow ripple effect on Dialog item click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ripple

I am getting a yellow square ripple effect when clicking on Dialog clickable items but I have set the background borderless, why the yellow color? I have not done anything.

[image: Screenshot]

**DIALOG:**

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.show();
```

**ITEM:**

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
            app:tint="@color/nameColor"
            android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: Same here, probably its inherited from the dialog parent style.